# Rails shows IP as 127.0.0.1 when accessed from private NIC, but Nginx shows the correct IP. Public IP gets forwarded fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, nginx, ip, unicorn

We are running a Rails application on Unicorn + Nginx. The server has two NICs that we use. `eth0` handles requests for the public internet, and `eth2` handles requests from our private network.

When a request comes through `eth0`, the nginx logs show the public IP, and the Rails logs also show this IP. However, when a request comes through `eth2`, the nginx logs show the private IP correctly (e.g. `192.168.5.134`), but the Rails logs show `127.0.0.1`.

So it seems like public requests on `eth0` get their `X-Forwarded-For` header set correctly, but this isn't happening for requests on `eth2`.

Our nginx config is pretty basic:

```
upstream example.com {
  server unix://var/www/example.com/shared/sockets/unicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

...

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ...

  location @example.com  {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_Addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if ($host ~* "^(.+)\.example.com$") {
      set $subdomain $1;
    }

    proxy_pass http://example.com;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that Rails thinks any `192.168.x.x` address is a private address, so strips them from the `X-Forwarded_For` header.

```
# IP addresses that are "trusted proxies" that can be stripped from
# the comma-delimited list in the X-Forwarded-For header. See also:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces
TRUSTED_PROXIES = %r{
  ^127\.0\.0\.1$                | # localhost
  ^(10                          | # private IP 10.x.x.x
    172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]) | # private IP in the range 172.16.0.0 .. 172.31.255.255
    192\.168                      # private IP 192.168.x.x
   )\.
}x
```

See the relevant Rails source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb#L47-58) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb#L74-77).

One solution is to add this to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies = /^127\.0\.0\.1$/ # localhost
```

That way, IPs on your local network will not be replaced by '127.0.0.1'.