# How to log real client ip in rails log when behind proxy like nginx

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, nginx, reverse-proxy

#### Problem

I have a rails 3.2.15 with rack 1.4.5 setup on two servers. First server is a nginx proxy serving static assets. Second server is a unicorn serving the rails app.

In Rails `production.log` I always see the nginx IP address (10.0.10.150) and not my client IP address (10.0.10.62):

```
Started GET "/" for 10.0.10.150 at 2013-11-21 13:51:05 +0000
```

I want to have the real client IP in logs.

#### Our Setup

The HTTP headers `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Real-IP` are setup correctly in nginx and I have defined `10.0.10.62` as not being a trusted proxy address by setting `config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies = /^127\.0\.0\.1$/` in `config/environments/production.rb`, thanks to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19904490/177665). I can check it is working because I log them in the application controller:

in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :log_ips

    def log_ips
        logger.info("request.ip = #{request.ip} and request.remote_ip = #{request.remote_ip}")
    end
end
```

in `production.log`:

```
request.ip = 10.0.10.150 and request.remote_ip = 10.0.10.62
```

#### Investigation

When investigating, I saw that [`Rails::Rack::Logger`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.15/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb) is responsible for logging the IP address:

```
def started_request_message(request)
  'Started %s "%s" for %s at %s' % [
    request.request_method,
    request.filtered_path,
    request.ip,
    Time.now.to_default_s ]
end
```

`request` is an instance of [`ActionDispatch::Request`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.15/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb). It inherits [`Rack::Request`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.5/lib/rack/request.rb) which defines how the IP address is computed:

```
def trusted_proxy?(ip)
  ip =~ /^127\.0\.0\.1$|^(10|172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|30|31)|192\.168)\.|^::1$|^fd[0-9a-f]{2}:.+|^localhost$/i
end

def ip
  remote_addrs = @env['REMOTE_ADDR'] ? @env['REMOTE_ADDR'].split(/[,\s]+/) : []
  remote_addrs.reject! { |addr| trusted_proxy?(addr) }

  return remote_addrs.first if remote_addrs.any?

  forwarded_ips = @env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ? @env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].strip.split(/[,\s]+/) : []

  if client_ip = @env['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
    # If forwarded_ips doesn't include the client_ip, it might be an
    # ip spoofing attempt, so we ignore HTTP_CLIENT_IP
    return client_ip if forwarded_ips.include?(client_ip)
  end

  return forwarded_ips.reject { |ip| trusted_proxy?(ip) }.last || @env["REMOTE_ADDR"]
end
```

The forwarded IP address are filtered with `trusted_proxy?`. Because our nginx server is using a public IP address and not a private IP address, `Rack::Request#ip` thinks it is not a proxy but the real client ip that tries to do some IP spoofing. That's why I see nginx IP address in my logs.

In log excerpts, client and servers have IP address 10.0.10.x because I am using virtual machines to reproduce our production environment.

#### Our current solution

To circumvent this behavior, I wrote a little Rack middleware located in app/middleware/remote_ip_logger.rb:

```
class RemoteIpLogger
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    remote_ip = env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"]
    Rails.logger.info "Remote IP: #{remote_ip}" if remote_ip
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

And I insert it just after the `ActionDispatch::RemoteIp` middleware

```
config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, "RemoteIpLogger"
```

This way I can see the real client IP in logs:

```
Started GET "/" for 10.0.10.150 at 2013-11-21 13:59:06 +0000
Remote IP: 10.0.10.62
```

I feel a little uncomfortable with this solution. nginx+unicorn is a common setup for rails application. If I have to log the client IP myself, it means I have missed something. Is it because the Nginx server is using a public IP address when communicating with the rails server? Is there a way to customize the `trusted_proxy?` method of `Rack::Request`?

**EDITED**: add nginx configuration and a HTTP request capture

`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site.example.com.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name    site.example.com;
    listen         80;


    location ^~ /assets/ {
       root /home/deployer/site/shared;
       expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
      root /home/deployer/site/current/public;
      try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
      access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.access.log combined_proxy;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_read_timeout 300;

      proxy_pass http://rails.example.com:8080;
    }
}
```

Nginx server is `10.0.10.150`. Rails server is `10.0.10.190`. My machine is `10.0.10.62` When doing `curl http://10.0.10.150/` from my machine, a `tcpdump port 8080 -i eth0 -Aq -s 0` on rails server show theses request HTTP headers:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.10.62
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Host: 10.0.10.150
Connection: close
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Accept: */*
```

And the rails log `/home/deployer/site/current/log/production.log` (*Remote IP* and *request.ip* lines being added by custom code):

```
Started GET "/" for 10.0.10.150 at 2013-11-22 08:01:17 +0000
Remote IP: 10.0.10.62
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as */*
request.ip = 10.0.10.150 and request.remote_ip = 10.0.10.62
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_landing.html.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8.9ms (Views: 7.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: what's your nginx config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion, your current approach is the only sane one. The only step that is missing is overwriting the IP address in `env`.

The typical REMOTE_ADDR seldom holds the correct IP if you've any amount of layers of proxies and load balancers and what not -- you're not unique in this respect. Each potentially adds or changes remote IP-related headers. And you cannot assume that each of those fields necessarily correspond to a single IP address, at that. Some will push or unshift an IP to a list instead.

There is only one way to know for sure which field holds the correct value and how, and that is to dive in there and look. You've evidently done that already. Now, just overwrite `env['REMOTE_ADDR']` with its correct value using your Rack middleware. There's little point in letting any piece of code you didn't write log or process the wrong IP address, as is happening now.

(This being Ruby, you could also monkey patch Rack::Request, of course...)

For colorful reading that illustrate the varying degrees of which exotic setups can mess up attempts at finding a client's real IP address, see for instance the unending discussions that occurred about this for WordPress:

- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9235
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4198
- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4602

It's PHP but the gist of the points raised apply equally well to Ruby. (Note that they're unresolved as I write this, too, and that they've been around for aeons.)

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I just find it strange to customize rails behavior for such a typical configuration. I expected rails to automatically log both ip addresses and thought I misconfigured it.

Answer (score 5):

This seemed to do the trick for me.  (set in nginx config)

```
   proxy_set_header CLIENT_IP $remote_addr;
```

Comment: I think this will get detected by rails as an IP spoof attack unless the ip address is in the list of trusted_proxies.

Comment: This is was helpfull, but for me - not exactly. I'm set `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;` in location section. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue, that a subset of our web clients access our rails app on (Rails 4.2.7) on our private network and we get the wrong IP reported. So, I thought I'd add what worked for us to resolve the problem.

I found [Rails issue 5223](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5223) that provided a better workaround than double logging the IP like the question does. So, we monkey patch Rack to remove the private network from the list of trusted proxies like so:

```
module Rack
  class Request
    def trusted_proxy?(ip)
      ip =~ /^127\.0\.0\.1$/
    end
  end
end
```

That addresses the controller logging the wrong IP, the other half of the fix to ensure that `request.remote_ip` is handled correctly. To do so add the following to your config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.action_dispatch.trusted_proxies = [IPAddr.new('127.0.0.1')]
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. To fix this I referred your implementation, just below the line in `config/application.rb` made it fixed.

```
config.middleware.insert_before Rails::Rack::Logger, 'RemoteIpLogger'
```

No need to write extra loggers you will see actual client IP in the first row itself.

```
Started GET "/" for 10.0.10.62 at 2013-11-22 08:01:17 +0000
```

And in `app\middleware\remote_ip_logger.rb`. My `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is having a list of IPs and the first one is the actual client's IP.

```
class RemoteIpLogger
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
      remote_ip = env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].split(",")[0]
      env['REMOTE_ADDR'] = env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"] = env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] = remote_ip
      @app.call(env)
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Short and simple :

```
request.remote_ip
```

Comment: Indeed, that's how you get the remote ip. If you read the question carefully, you'll see I used it to log it "manually". My concern was why is Rails logging another value than `request.remote_ip` and how to fix it.